# Why can't I build the Sydney Opera House in Civ5?

Tags: civilization-5

I have researched Globalization and no other civ has yet built the Sydney Opera House wonder, yet it is not available in the production list of my city!?

Neither the Civilopedia nor the manual lists any building restrictions on this wonder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Sydney Opera House wonder can only be built in a coastal city, although this is not mentioned in its description.